# Basic structure for developing with jQuery and Ajax in MVC (PHP)

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-mobile

I was hoping someone could share some advice on the file structure a mobile app with jQuery Mobile, Ajax and PHP.

I am pretty new to Ajax and I am struggling to integrate it into my MVC framework.
I have my Models, Views and Controller files and normally I would simply use my Controllers to feed my Views with the data from the Models.

However, when using Ajax, I understand that you can not POST (or GET) data to a specific function in a Controller directly. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

What is the best practice here?

1. Create a specific Ajax Controller with no functions?
2. Have a separate "connecting" php-file and post the Ajax call to that file which then calls the Controller files and retrieves the data.

Any ideas and maybe even some sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can post to a specific function in a controller. Why should it not work? Just post your data to the url where you call your function in a controller.

Comment: It won't be possible to supply sample code, since we'd be guessing what will work in your specific framework. Essentially, jQuery and AJAX is separate from your framework/models - just create a page that reads the data from the AJAX request and replies in a form that the request can understand, and you should be fine. What you do inside that page is up to you.

Comment: So, create a page/action (or whatever it is called in your framework) in your controller, and read in your get/post parameters from your AJAX operation, and then reply via `echo` or something in your page template. You may need to wire this into your routing configuration if you're using pretty URLs. It is common to reply either in HTML fragments or JSON.

Comment: @Jurik - I saw a post somewhere someone was saying you could only call pages and not functions. Preferably I would like to have an ajax_controller and call it directly. However, I have tried with the url like so `url: '/ajax/includes/controllers/ajax/getFilteredTypes'`, but it just returns undefined for my return values, but the same works if I place it in a php file and calls it. @halfer:- I am not using any framework, but maybe it's a good idea. I am waiting for the beta version of Yii 2.0.

Comment: @MattDrake , I am working with Yii too and I do not get your problem. It is like halfer said, your ajax call just has to go against the url that calls the controller/function. So if you have an ajax controller named `AjaxController` with a function `actionGetSomeData` the url would be `www.yourdomain.com/ajax/getsomedata`.

Comment: @Jurik - At the moment I am just developing on my computer and the site is local on http://localhost/ajax, would that then mean that the URL I should be calling is `http://localhost/ajax/ajax/getSomeData`?

Comment: Yes or just relative path `ajax/getSomeData` - check out my answer.

Comment: @Jurik - I know this is a late reply, but I finally found the post I was referring to earlier.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577905/how-to-call-a-php-controller-method-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you do it with Yii framework.

This is your ajax class 'AjaxController.php':

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

  /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    *
    * @return array access control rules
    */
  public function accessRules()
  {
    return array(
      array('allow',
    'actions' => array('foo', 'bar'),
    'users' => array('?'),
  ),
      array('allow',
    'actions' => array('foo', 'bar'),
    'users' => array('*'),
  ),
      array('allow',
    'actions' => array('foo', 'bar','regform'),
    'users' => array('@'),
  ),
      array('deny',  // deny all users
    'users' => array('*'),
      ),
    );
  }
  // [...] all the common Yii Controller functions

  public function actionRegform()
  {
    //get some data from database
    $data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('some sql')->queryRow();
    //or render a view
    $this->render('regform', array('mydata' => $dataFromDb));
    //push out everything you want
    echo 'my function was called!';
  }
}
```

In your javascript you just call the url `/ajax/regform` and your MVC will know that `ajax` is the controller and `actionRegform` the function you are calling.

**Do not forget to implement your function to the access rules of this controller.**

Comment: Thanks @Jurik, this is exactly what I want to do. I can't figure out why I cannot get it to work? Maybe I have to start using Yii. Not sure what the access rules of the Controller is?

Comment: @MattDrake I added the rules function. Hmm did you create this controller with `gii`? Because that is the recommended way to create classes if you do not know the whole structure.

Comment: Actually, I think I have figured it out now. It has something to do with the subdomain in my URL. I tried it with the site in the web root folder (http://localhost, instead of http://localhost/ajax) and then it is working the way you described? Any idea how that could be?

Comment: That is just a folder, not a subdomain. I think you have to set the `basePath` in `configWeb` in your `main.php` to the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that You are using AJAX doesn't change much, the simplest way to use AJAX on your site is to put an extra `POST` (try not to use `GET`) parameter with will help You to determine if this is AJAX request. It can be just `ajax=1`. Then You can make a seperate `view` to show only those things that should be shown by ajax. this can be done on every components separately, or just in Your main `index.php` (or whatever your mine view file is called). In this file give some code like this:

```
if( ( isset($_POST['ajax']) ) and ( $_POST['ajax'] == 1 ) ){
    echo just_main_content();// or $component->content - whatever You use
}else{
    //normal page code
}
```

I believe that this is the easiest way

Comment: @bumerand - Do you mean if I am posting an Ajax request to another view? I would probably use separate pages for the Ajax calls. However, I would prefer to call a function directly for the data.

Comment: That sounds like a rest api. You can do this with Yii as well.